# Python, MySQLdb, multiple Sequential statements (First Select, Then Insert)

Tags: python, mysql-python

Very newb.

Have the following

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT email,id FROM list")
userData = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO campaigns(date) VALUES('Now')")
```

the first part works, the second does not (realize it wouldn't enter actual datetime), just trying to see if it will insert into database.

Why doesn't this work?  I'm hoping to avoid having many db. entries with same username/passes.

I figured it would work?  userData would contain what I want, and then cursor.execute would do afterwards.

Thanks!

[edit]

I actually tried to just do an insert statement by itself, and its not working?!?  Any reason this should NOT work?

```
import mysqldb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="host", port=3306, user="python", passwd="test", db="python")
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO campaigns(date) VALUES ('est')"
cursor.execute(sql)
```

The above code the SELECT statement works fine.

Comment: Can you post the error? and please look at : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now, this may fix your problem, replacing 'now' with NOW().

Comment: there is no error...it just doesnt make a new entry.

Comment: I've actually just tried doing my single insert statement--and that is not working.  Have no idea why.  Tried logging in to phpMyAdmin under user/pass that my python program uses, and used exact same sql statement, and it works!?

Comment: can you take a look at my above edits?

Comment: got it figured out.  needed to do db.commit()

Answer (score 2):

Solution was that I needed to do db.commit()